# Suppressing Rows, based on values in the results

Tags: sql, sql-server

i cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.

there are unlimited number of groupIDs, and a set of about 5 processIDs. 
which to show, depends on the processIDs that are present within the groupID.

i have a table that has the following, simplified, set up:

```
groupID int
processID int
```

where, the group ID is the same for each transaction. Each transaction can have multiple processes, belonging to the group.

with values as shown below, for example:

```
Group ID   ProcessID    
1           1x2
1           1x2
1           2y4 
1           2y4
1           3u7
1           4i9
1           5x4
```

i need to write query that will only return process id 4, if 1x2, 2y4 and 4i9 all exist for the same group, suppressing 1x2 and 2y4. if only 1x2 and 2y4 exist, return 2y4, suppressing 1x2 from the results set.

so, if for a given processID i have 1x2,2y4,4i9 the output would look like:

```
1x2 4i9
```

There is also possibility that if 1x2 and 5x4 exist on the same group, i need to only show 1x2.

the query displays dozens of columns, i was hoping to do this without group by's if possible, but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: You need to return a row with the largest value of `ProcessID` for each group, right?

Comment: they are not numeric values, i've just updated the question. should have been more clear, my fault

Comment: Your logic is not clear. How many rows you need per group?

Comment: only 1 row per group will show, buti need to use the other processIDs to figure out which one to show. it is not always the "biggest" one showing

Comment: Please provide a complete definition of the rules that you want to apply, with corresponding sample data and expected results. Or maybe split your requirements into several consistent questions?

Comment: You keep repeating the same thing, but it still doesn't make sense of what you need.

Comment: So what IS the rule for deciding which ProcessId to show???   You've told us it isn't necessarily the biggest, but you never say what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `max()`:

```
select groupId, max(processId)
from t
group by groupId;
```

Comment: unfortunately, max wont' work, this example is very simplified. and the 1,2,3, are alphanumeric representations of the processID. i need actual login in my where statement i can mold into my data :( i just made the change to the original question to show this.

Comment: thanks, but in some cases i would need 1 and, let's say 6 suppressed, if 5 is also in the same groupID, to only show 5....

Comment: @MadamZuZu - Then define these cases.  Unless you are able to describe your **entire** task we wouldn't be able to help you.

Comment: one of the cases is , if 1x2, 2y4 and 4i9 all exist for the same group, only show a row for 4i9.